# SessionState child Applications

Tags: web-applications, session-variables

I have 2 websites

```
WebsiteRoot - MVC Website (c#)
```

and under this site i have a child Application

```
UI - Webforms (VB)
```

so it looks like

```
WebsiteRoot
WebsiteRoot/UI
```

I have the `web.config` and the `Global.asax` set up in the WebsiteRoot project and all settings inherit properly so i can read them.

What my problem is the session has the same machine key(inherited) and same session name(inherited) and both sites use the same sessionID(verified by looking at runtime) but in the child application the session has no items.

Is there any explanation for why this is happening